# Fastest way to delete a piece of code and its connected code in project (in Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

I imported a project in Android Studio. It's a very complex code. There's a TabView. I want to replace 2 of the 3 tabs with some new code. What is the fastest way in Android Studio to delete their content and every associated class/method/line in the project?

Edit: For better understanding:
I have for example 3 methods: method1(), method2(), method3()
I simply want to delete everything in the project related to method2() and method3() so I can replace it with any content:
I want to delete all of the submethods, too: method2(), method2.1(), method2.2(), method2.3(), method2.1.1(), method2.1.2(), method3(), method 3.1(), etc.
How can I do this automatically in Android Studio?

Comment: Please add more clarification of what you want to achieve ; with code sample or picture that makes it clear

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips that may help:

1. To find usages of a single method/variable across the entire project

   Either hold **CTRL + Left Mouse click** on this method/variable; so you can see wherever they are used.

   Or **Right Mouse click on this method/variable >> Find Usages**
2. To safely delete a method usage from the entire project:

   Either **Right Mouse click on this method/variable >> Refactor >> Safe Delete**

   Or **Alt + Delete**

   **Note**: This doesn't include deleting global methods/variables that are wrapped in the method intended to be deleted .. I am not sure if Android Studio supports this or not.
3. To search for some text in your entire project which includes almost everything in your project including SDK stuff, like method/field names, namespace, Strings, XML attributes, and so on

   **Edit >> Find >> Find in path…**
4. To search for text in your entire project which includes in file
   names, field/method/class names

   Shift + Shift

Hope this could help you.

Comment: "Note: This doesn't include deleting global methods/variables that are wrapped in the method intended to be deleted .. I am not sure if Android Studio supports this or not."

What a pitty because this would be exactly what I need...

Comment: You would need to safe delete every individual field.. Even better than manual delete.